# No puedo mostrar datos pedidos por query, muestra la query

Tags: php, mysql

Intento mostrar datos almacenados en una db, estoy trabajando php como mvc y al momento de mostrar la pantalla con las consultas pertinentes me muestra la consulta y no los datos, a continuación dejo una foto.

[image: aqui deberia desplegar el menu que indica la query]

**class.Conexion.php**

```
<?php

class Conexion extends mysqli {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct('localhost','root','123','nielsendb_temp');
        $this->query("SET NAMES utf8;");
        $this->connect_errno ? die('ERROR: Datos incorrectos en /core/models/class.Conexion.php'): null;

    }

    public function rows($x){
        return mysqli_num_rows($x);
    }

    public function recorrer($x){
        return msqli_fetch_array($x);
    }

    public function liberar($x){
        return mysqli_free_result($x);
    }

    public function preparada(){
        return mysqli_stmt_init();
    }
    public function conectar(){
        return mysqli_query();
    }
}

?>
```

**indexControler.php**

```
<?php

include('core/models/class.Conexion.php');


$template = new Smarty();
$template->display('home/index.tpl');

?>
```

**index.tpl**

```
   {include 'overall/header.tpl'}
    {include 'overall/menu.php'}
    {include 'overall/carrusel.tpl'}  
    {include 'overall/contenedor.php'}
    {include 'overall/footer.tpl'}
```

**menu.php**

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <img class="navbar-brand" src="/noticias/img/n1.png" style="width: 150px;height: 50px;">

            <?php
            $db = new Conexion();
            alert($db);
                $rscons= $db->mysqli_query("Select admin from tblusuario");

                $rs=mysqli_fetch_array($rscons);
                if ($rs["admin"]==1)
                {
                    $obtenermenu= $db->mysqli_query("Select idopcion,descripcion,glyphicon from tblnoticias_menu order By PosI");
                    while($menu=mysqli_fetch_array($obtenermenu))
                    {
                        $submenu= $db->mysqli_query("Select idsubmenu,url,descripcion,glyphicon from tblsubmenu where idopcion='$menu[idopcion]' and estado=1 Order By PosS");
                        if(mysqli_num_rows($submenu)>0) 
                        {
                            ?>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="fa <?php echo $menu['glyphicon']; ?>"></i><span><?php echo utf8_encode($menu['descripcion']); ?></span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                            </a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <?php
                            while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($submenu))
                            {
                                ?>

                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo " ../../ ".$row1['url'];?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i><?php echo utf8_encode($row1['descripcion']); ?></a>
                            </li>

                            <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <?php
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    $obtenermenu= $db->mysqli_query("Select M.idopcion,M.descripcion,glyphicon from tblperfilesuser P inner Join tblmenu M On P.Idopcion=M.IdOpcion Group By M.idopcion,M.descripcion Order By PosI");
                    while($menu=mysqli_fetch_array($obtenermenu))
                    {
                        $submenu= $db->mysqli_query("Select S.idsubmenu,S.url,S.descripcion,glyphicon from tblperfilesuser P inner Join tblsubmenu S On P.idopcion=S.idopcion And P.idSubmenu=S.IdSubMenu where P.idopcion='$menu[idopcion]' And  estado=1 Order By PosS");
                        if(mysqli_num_rows($submenu)>0)
                        {
                            ?>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa <?php echo $menu['glyphicon']; ?>"></i><span><?php echo utf8_encode($menu['descripcion']); ?></span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                            </a>

                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <?php
                            while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($submenu))
                            {
                                ?>

                                <li>
                                    <a href="<?php echo " ../../ ".$row1['url'];?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i><?php echo utf8_encode($row1['descripcion']); ?></a>
                                </li>

                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                        }
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </ul>

    </nav>
    <?php
        $db->close();

?>
  </div>
```

Comment: Si quieres incluir código php directamente en el template usando Smarty tienes que usar `{php}` en lugar de `<?php` https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.php.tpl

Comment: @JuanmiRodriguez deberías poner ese comentario como respuesta.

Comment: juanmi cuando pongo {php} me da este error Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template "C:\laragon\www\noticiasmvc\styles\templates\overall\menu.php" on line 7 "{php}" missing closing tag '{/php}' <-- thrown in C:\laragon\www\noticiasmvc\core\libs\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 7 luego incluyo el closing tap {/php} y me da otro error

Comment: Tienes que cerrar con `{/php}`en lugar de `?>` @AlvaroMontoro No lo considero una respuesta porque en realidad no muestro una versión del código funcionando y en realidad no es la forma correcta de usar Smarty, es más bien un apaño

Comment: Juanmi el problema es que {php} y {/php} se usa para los tpl y yo estoy trabajando php, por ende uso { } y siento que estoy haciendolo de mala manera ya que mvc no debiera tener vistas con consultas pero para salir del apuro requiero mostrar los datos y no las querys

Comment: Perdona no me había fijado en el nombre del fichero. En la página de Smarty que he enlazado lo explica, o bien llamas el fichero `menu.tpl` y usas los `{php}` o lo dejas como está pero entonces tienes que incluirlo con `{php} include('overall/menu.php'); {/php}` Estás mezclando los dos y por eso te muestra el código.

Comment: Juanmi haciendo lo que me dices de enlazar el codigo con {php} include('overall/menu.php'); {/php} me manda este error:
Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template "C:\laragon\www\noticiasmvc\styles\templates\home\index.tpl" on line 2 "{php} include('overall/menu.php'); {/php}" {php}[/php} tags not allowed. Use SmartyBC to enable them <-- thrown in C:\laragon\www\noticiasmvc\core\libs\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No utilizo Smarty pero leyendo la documentación encontramos [{include_php}](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.include.php.tpl).

> **{Include_php}** está obsoleto, se recomienda usar plugins
>   para aislar correctamente la presentación del código de la aplicación.
>   A partir de Smarty 3.1, las etiquetas {include_php} sólo están
>   disponibles en SmartyBC.

**NO se recomienda** usar código php en las vistas Smarty. De hecho esta obsoleto y debería evitarse.

Si aun así quiere utilizarlo el archivo index.tpl deberia quedar así:

**index.tpl**

```
{include 'overall/header.tpl'}
{include_php file='overall/menu.php'}
{include 'overall/carrusel.tpl'}  
{include_php 'overall/contenedor.php'}
{include 'overall/footer.tpl'}
```

---

---

La forma correcta sería hacer las consultas en el controlador `indexControler.php` y pasar los resultados a la vista para recorrerlos.

Algo así:

indexControler.php

```
<?php

include('core/models/class.Conexion.php');
$db = new Conexion();

// creamos un array para las opciones del menu
$menuOption = array();

$rscons= $db->mysqli_query("Select admin from tblusuario");
$rs=mysqli_fetch_array($rscons);

if ($rs["admin"]==1){
    $obtenermenu= $db->mysqli_query("Select idopcion,descripcion,glyphicon from tblnoticias_menu order By PosI");
    while($menu=mysqli_fetch_array($obtenermenu))
    {
        // supongo que el id es un entero poreso me aseguro de que asi sea para no tener problemas
        $idMenu = (int) $menu['idopcion'];
        $submenu = $db->mysqli_query("Select idsubmenu,url,descripcion,glyphicon from tblsubmenu where idopcion=".$idMenu." and estado=1 Order By PosS");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($submenu)>0) 
        {
            // añadimos el submenu al menu principal
            $menu['submenu'] = mysqli_fetch_all($submenu, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        }

        // volcamos el menu y submenu a $menuOption
        $menuOption['menu'] = $menu;
        // indicamos se es admin o no
        $menuOption['admin'] = true;
    }
}
else{
    // esto es casi lo mismo que antes pero adaptando las consultas
    $obtenermenu= $db->mysqli_query("Select M.idopcion,M.descripcion,glyphicon from tblperfilesuser P inner Join tblmenu M On P.Idopcion=M.IdOpcion Group By M.idopcion,M.descripcion Order By PosI");
    while($menu=mysqli_fetch_array($obtenermenu))
    {
        $idMenu = (int) $menu['idopcion'];
        $submenu= $db->mysqli_query("Select S.idsubmenu,S.url,S.descripcion,glyphicon from tblperfilesuser P inner Join tblsubmenu S On P.idopcion=S.idopcion And P.idSubmenu=S.IdSubMenu where P.idopcion=".$idMenu." And  estado=1 Order By PosS");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($submenu)>0) 
        {
            $menu['submenu'] = mysqli_fetch_all($submenu, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        }

        $menuOption['menu'] = $menu;
        $menuOption['admin'] = false;        
    }   
}

$db->close();

$template = new Smarty();
// asignamos el array para tenerlo disponible en la vista
$template->assign('menuOption', $menuOption);

$template->display('home/index.tpl');


// es mejor no cerrar los archivos que solo contienen php
//?>
```

index.tpl

```
{include 'overall/header.tpl'}
// menu debe ser .tpl en lugar de .php
{include 'overall/menu.tpl'}
{include 'overall/carrusel.tpl'} 

// este archivo lo tendras que corregir
//{include 'overall/contenedor.php'}

{include 'overall/footer.tpl'}
```

menu.php

Utilizamos la sintaxis de Smarty para recorrer el array que pasamos en el controlador

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <img class="navbar-brand" src="/noticias/img/n1.png" style="width: 150px;height: 50px;">
            {if $menuOption["admin"] eq true}
                {foreach key=clave item=menu from=$menuOption}
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="fa {$menu['glyphicon']}"></i><span>{$menu['descripcion']}</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            {foreach key=subClave item=subMenu from=$menu['submenu']}
                                <li>
                                    <a href="../../{$subMenu['url']}"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>{$subMenu['descripcion']}</a>
                                </li>
                            {/foreach}
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                {/foreach}
            {else}
                {foreach key=clave item=menu from=$menuOption}
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa {$menu['glyphicon']}"></i><span>{$menu['descripcion']}</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            {foreach key=subClave item=subMenu from=$menu['submenu']}
                                <li>
                                    <a href="../../{$row1['url']}"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>{$row1['descripcion']}</a>
                                </li>
                            {/foreach}
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                {/foreach}
            {/if}
        </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

> Es posible que estos script contengan algún error, no los pude probar.

Comment: da error, ya que no puede ingresar a la clase conexion, tampoco funciona {include_php file='overall/menu.php'} esto no xiste en smarty, fracias de todas formas

Comment: Fue eliminado en la version 3.1 en adelante, por otro lado puedes explicar un poco mas lo que te falla? @720TA

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Conexion' not found in C:\laragon\www\noticiasmvc\core\models\class.Conectar.php:5 Stack trace: #0 C:\laragon\www\noticiasmvc\core\controlers\indexController.php(2): include() #1 C:\laragon\www\noticiasmvc\index.php(5): include_once('C:\\laragon\\www\\...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\noticiasmvc\core\models\class.Conectar.php on line 5
ese es el error que da igual hice unos cambios con la respuesta que me diste pero me sigue indicando ese error lo unico que hice fue cambiar la consulta al modelo no al controller pero de tu forma o la mia manda eso

Comment: Por el error que te da es como si no estuvieses haciendo el include de la clase `Conexion`, por lo que al instanciarla no la encuentra. @720TA

Comment: include('core/models/class.Conexion.php');
$db = new Conexion(); incluyo de esa manera
y las carpetas estan de esta forma :
noticiasmvc
|->core
   |->controlers
         |->indexController.php
   |->models
         |->class.Conexion.php
         |->class.Conectar.php

Comment: No había dado cuenta de que tenias 2 archivos `class.Conexion.php` y `class.Conectar.php`, el error te dice que no encuentra la clase `Conexion` en el archivo `class.Conectar.php`. revisa esto por que algo no cuadra en tus archivos de conexion. @720TA

Comment: gracias de todas formas <3 estoy intentado ver cual es el problema pero smarty se me a hecho demasiado complicado para implementar de un día a otro